# I have a type mismatch between 'com/google/type/LatLng' and 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage' and can't tell why

Tags: java, type-conversion, datastore, protobuf-java, value-class

I am trying to obtain a Value class type (from google.datastore.v1) from a Long type, or even an Integer, and can't seem to be able to do so.

Here is the portion of code that seems to be reluctant

```java
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value;

public class EntityHelper {
  public static Value makeValue(final Long value) {
    Value.Builder builder = Value.newBuilder();
    builder.setIntegerValue(value);
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

When ran, this code is generating the following error :

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:375)
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/datastore/v1/Value$Builder.setGeoPointValue(Lcom/google/type/LatLng$Builder;)Lcom/google/datastore/v1/Value$Builder; @30: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/type/LatLng' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @30
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/datastore/v1/Value$Builder', 'com/google/type/LatLng$Builder' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/SingleFieldBuilder', 'com/google/type/LatLng' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 001a c700 122a 2bb6 007c b500 102a
    0x0000010: b600 37a7 000f 2ab4 001a 2bb6 007c b600
    0x0000020: 5a57 2a10 08b5 0009 2ab0               
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@22)
    same_frame(@34)

    at com.google.datastore.v1.Value.toBuilder(Value.java:749)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.Value.newBuilder(Value.java:743)
    at com.app.data.impl.objectify.EntityHelper.makeValue(EntityHelper.java:931)
    at com.app.data.impl.objectify.EntityHelper.makeValue(EntityHelper.java:903)
    at com.app.apps.client.data.impl.BookingDao.getContactBookings(BookingDao.java:123)
    at com.app.apps.client.reporting.Endpoints.getContactListBookingsDataResponse(Endpoints.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:351)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.dispatcher.PathDispatcher.dispatch(PathDispatcher.java:50)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
    at com.app.apps.client.servlet.InitializerFilter.doFilter(InitializerFilter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at net.lightoze.gwt.i18n.server.I18nFilter.doFilter(I18nFilter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.slim3.datastore.DatastoreFilter.doFilter(DatastoreFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:213)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:757)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:720)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:690)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:882)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can't seem to figure out why is this error generated and what I have to do to fix it, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas here:

```
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value;

public class EntityHelper {
  public static Value makeValue(final Long value) {
     Value.Builder builder = Value.newBuilder();
     builder.setIntegerValue(value);
     return builder.build();
  }
}
```

First, is you're setting a long to an integer. By definition, that would cause data loss since a long is 8 bytes and an integer is 4 bytes.

You could try setting the type to a type that will be compatible with you're trying to use.

Usually, latitude and longitude are represented as doubles.
Hopefully that helps you troubleshoot.

I am not sure which LatLng object you're using but here is an example

[https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/cluster/navigation/LatLng]

As an example it you might try this:

```
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value;

public class EntityHelper {
  public static Value makeValue(final Double value) {
     Value.Builder builder = Value.newBuilder();
     builder.setDoubleValue(value);
     return builder.build();
  }
}
```

I am not certain as to your implementation, however another option would be to use
LatLng.Builder  getGeoPointValueBuilder()

In this example, you would implement something like as follows:

... will need different imports ...

```
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value;

public class EntityHelper {
  public static LatLng makeLatLng(final LatLng value) {
     LatLng.Builder builder = LatLng.Builder.newBuilder(); 
     builder.setLatLng(value);
     return builder.build();
  }
}
```

As I said, I am not sure which API you're using but maybe poke around here to tailor your solution:

[http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/type/LatLng.html]